# Meaning of the derivative of cross entropy wrt $p(x)$

Tags: entropy, derivative, cross-entropy

Lets define the cross entropy between 2 probability distributions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ as

$$H(p,q) = -\sum p(x) \log{q(x)} $$

What would be the meaning of derivative of $H(p,q)$ when taking the derivative wrt $p$ ?

Comment: $p$ is a discrete function, so it seems.  Do not see how to compute a derivative wrt $p$ unless you mean sometihing like a functional derivative.